# How do I refactor the repetitive code in JavaScript? (Includes Array)

Tags: javascript, arrays, api, loops, async-await

I am using **TMDb Movie API**.
This is my code so far

**index.html**

```
<div id="trending-movies">
   //display movies here
</div>
<div id="popular-movies">
   //display movies here
</div>
<div id="toprated-movies">
   //display movies here
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
let trending = document.getElementById("trending-movies");
let popular = document.getELementById("popular-movies");
let topRated = document.getElementById("toprated-movies");

async function getMovies(url) {
  const res = await fetch(url);
  return await res.json();
}
async function loadMovies() {
    let data = await Promise.all([
      getMovies(
        `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/upcoming?api_key=${key}`
      ),
      getMovies(
        `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=${key}`
      ),
      getMovies(
        `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/top_rated?api_key=${key}`
      ),
    ]);
const result = data.map(e=>e.results);
result[0].map((item) => {
  const title= item.title;
  const id = item.id;
  //Add to trending container
});
result[1].map((item) => {
  const title= item.title;
  const id = item.id;
  //Add to popular container
});
result[2].map((item) => {
  const title= item.title;
  const id = item.id;
  //Add to upcoming container
});
  
}
loadMovies();
```

I am able to display the movies without any issue. My main concern is to eliminate the repeating code which is clearly seen above. Is there anyway to overcome this?

Comment: There's not a lot you can do here. Just some small improvements, as someone else has already answered. If you're fairly new to coding I strongly suggest you try reading up on how to write clean code rather than compact code. It's far better to be able to read the code quickly than to squeeze it onto less lines. You can learn this from reading/watching videos, failing that, you'll realise it yourself after a few years. Professional code reads like a good novel. You won't generally impress anyone with 1337 shorthand.

Answer (score 2):

The pattern I would use for code like this is to create a bunch of objects listing all the parameters I need for each iteration, and then iterate through those objects.  In this case, for each part, you need to know which DOM id to put the movies into, and what API call to do.  The `parts` array below provides exactly this information, and then it's easy to loop over.

```js
const parts = [
  {
    id: 'trending-movies',
    api: 'upcoming',
  },
  {
    id: 'popular-movies',
    api: 'popular',
  },
  {
    id: 'toprated-movies',
    api: 'top_rated',
  }
];

async function getMovies(url) {
  const res = await fetch(url);
  return await res.json();
}
async function loadMovies() {
  parts.forEach(({id, api}) => {
    const div = document.getElementById(id);
    const movies = await getMovies(
      `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${api}?api_key=${key}`
    );
    movies.map((item) => {
      const title = item.title;
      const id = item.id;
      //Add to div
    });
  });
}
loadMovies();
```

You could simplify this code further by making the `id`s of the `<div>` elements match the API calls.  But it might be nice to keep them separate, as API calls can change (e.g. if you switch from TMDB to some other service).

In the code above, I've also set up each promise to post results as soon as they're returned, which is more immediate.  But if you'd rather wait until all promises finish, as in your original code, you could do it similarly because we can index the `parts` array in the same way as the promise results:

```js
const parts = [
  {
    id: 'trending-movies',
    api: 'upcoming',
  },
  {
    id: 'popular-movies',
    api: 'popular',
  },
  {
    id: 'toprated-movies',
    api: 'top_rated',
  }
];

async function getMovies(url) {
  const res = await fetch(url);
  return await res.json();
}
async function loadMovies() {
  const data = await Promise.all(
    parts.map(({api}) =>
      getMovies(
        `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${api}?api_key=${key}`
      )
    )
  );
  parts.forEach(({id}, index) => {
    const div = document.getElementById(id);
    const movies = data[index];
    movies.map((item) => {
      const title = item.title;
      const id = item.id;
      //Add to div
    });
  });
}
loadMovies();
```

Comment: You might want to put in some try/catch blocks for the various `async` calls. Otherwise great answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the following method...

```
function mapTitle(item, element) {
  const title = item.title;
  const id = item.id;
  // Add to the container passed in as element parameter
}
```

Use it like:

```
result[0].map((item) => mapTitle(item, trending));
```

This could be improved further by adding the elements into an `elements` array (in order) and then calling this after the async function:

```
data.forEach((item, index) => mapTitle(item.results, elements[index]));
```